# Is there a way how to reconnect client from server side?

Tags: wcf

I have service application and i wonder if there is a way how can i try to reconnect to client from server after receive timeout runs out. I have method in client that calls server so it keeps channel open, but there can be some network error so i woder if there is a way how to try reach client after ICommunication.Closed event is fired.

Comment: Why not have the client handle the network loss and reconnect to svc?

Comment: I know how to do it that way but i would like to check if client is connected on server before i do some clean up

Comment: "Check if client is connected" is different from "reconnect client from server side". Which do you want to do?

Comment: I know sorry about that, i want to reconnect i know how to check if client is connected

Comment: You can't, because the client would then be the server :) The distinction between a server and a client is just about who connects and who accepts the connection (and usually the server can accept multiple clients, but that's not the main point).

Comment: That is a shame. Thank you anyway

Comment: Well ... you could make every client host an endpoint also. Effectively @Boris is right, because the client becomes a server. But with WCF, it is easily achievable, would be my guess. And maybe you can investigate using an asynchroneous callback option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx